# What exactly does int a do?

Tags: java

I am learning to code Java, and in a tutorial I learned to make the percentage of the percentage of wins I got. I am really confused what the integer "a" does exactly. Can someone please explain it in simple terms? (because I'm a complete newb)

```
    double numOfGames = 10000;
    double arrayNum = 1;
    Random r = new Random();

    int[] num = new int[(int) arrayNum]; // same as "= {0,0,0,0,0}
    boolean gameResult = true;
    boolean[] odds = new boolean[(int) numOfGames];
    double numOfWins = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a < numOfGames; a++) {

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            num[i] = r.nextInt(100) + 1;

            if (num[i] % 2 == 0) {

            } else {
                gameResult = false;
            }

        }

        if (gameResult) {
            odds[a] = true;
        }
        gameResult = true;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < odds.length; i++) {
        if (odds[i]) {
            numOfWins++;
        }
    }
    double perWin = (numOfWins / numOfGames) * 100;
    System.out.println(perWin + " % of an array with " + arrayNum
            + " positions.");
}
```

}

Comment: Please get into the habit of searching for [answers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) before posting questions -- particularly those of a very fundamental nature.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? check this out and you will see what it does.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSfhuSP3_oM

Comment: What do you mean by "does"? What exactly do you want explained? What part don't you understand? What part do you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a counter.

Basically it goes up by one every time that code block is run, in plain English this:

```
for (int a = 0; a < numOfGames; a++) {
  // Do things.
}
```

Is like saying "Start counting at 0; Do things repeatedly until the counter reaches `numOfGames`".

`a++` is just shorthand for `a = a + 1` or "add 1 to `a`".

Answer (score 1):

`int = a` is a local variable (an integer number) that increases by one in each iteration of your `for` loop. it simply goes from 0 to the total number of games, in this case: 10000. when it reaches the number of total games, it is discarded.